# How to find device type in expo react-native

Tags: react-native, expo

I found it a little time-consuming to figure out which device was using my app, as the documentation doesn't have many clear examples and other posts are lacking as well.

You can find that `getDeviceTypeAsync()` should get the device type but not how to read the result.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution put together from a few pieces of public code:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";

import { DeviceType, getDeviceTypeAsync } from "expo-device";

export default function DevelopmentScreen() {
  const deviceTypeMap = {
    [DeviceType.UNKNOWN]: "unknown",
    [DeviceType.PHONE]: "phone",
    [DeviceType.TABLET]: "tablet",
    [DeviceType.DESKTOP]: "desktop",
    [DeviceType.TV]: "tv",
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    getDeviceTypeAsync().then((deviceType) => {
      console.log(deviceTypeMap[deviceType]);
    });
  }, []);
  return null
}
```

Cheers!

Comment: its not working correct, iphone 12maxpro recognized as tablet, becouse big screen size